# jquery function is not working for me

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am learning jquery. I wrote an script but it is not working

1 My HTML

```
<ul id="recur" class="elasticstack">
    <li id=<?=$item['id']?>>.......</li>
    ....................................
</ul>
```

2 My jquery function

```
function viewDetails()
{
    $('#recur>li').live(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url:'myUrl'
            ,type:'post'
            ,dataType:'json'
            ,data:{propertyId:id}
            ,success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

where is my error? Thanks all!

Comment: What error are you getting? What's not working? Maybe clarify a **tad** / **whole lot** more to expand on your question. ***Note:*** `live()` is depreciated as of jQuery 1.7.

Comment: the basic, have you include jquery?

Comment: [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was removed in jQuery 1.9. See [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: You might want to consider `$.post()` for this as well

Comment: @Machavity `$.post` is just a shortcut for `$.ajax` with `type: 'POST'`

Comment: I see several mistakes (1) `.live('events', handler)` (2) `.live()` was removed in 1.9.0 (3) `viewDetails()` is never invoked -- no 'event' bound, no ajax runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have more id "recur" in same html.
Check your jquery library version for live function. you can use 1.8 version of library

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you've omitted the event you want handled for each `<li>` element. Let's assume *click* for now...

If you're using jQuery > 1.9, you cannot use `.live()`. Instead, use `.on()` with event delegation

```
$('#recur').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    var id = this.id;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'myUrl',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {propertyId: id}
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the quotes in the id. Try this:

```
<ul id="recur" class="elasticstack">
    <li id="<?=$item['id']?>">.......</li>
</ul>
```

You cant get the id because isn't there.

A better way to do the jQuery part is:

```
function viewDetails(){
    $('#recur').find('li).each(function(){
        $(this).on('click', function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                url:'myUrl'
                ,type:'post'
                ,dataType:'json'
                ,data:{propertyId:id}
                ,success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Don't use the `.live()` method. Is deprecated now. And with the .find() method you have better performance.

If you are dinamicaly adding the items and want to display the data every time an item is added, you can use the [livequery.js](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery) plugin, and do like this:

```
function viewDetails(){
    $('#recur li').livequery(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                url:'myUrl'
                ,type:'post'
                ,dataType:'json'
                ,data:{propertyId:id}
                ,success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in HTML

```
<ul id="recur" class="elasticstack">
    <li id="<?=$item['id']?>" >.......</li>
    ....................................
</ul>
```

In Ajax function

```
data:[{name:'propertyId', value:id}]
```

Comment: Why would the `data` property need to be an array?